# How can I know the full path node.js will require without running require

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I want to be able to know what path node's require will resolve to without running a require.

For example

```
var myVar = require('./some_module')
```

Internally node.js will look through its PATH, figure out whether it's a directory, a js file, a json file, etc., and then load the file.

Is there a way to just as for the full resolved path without actually loading the module?

The output I'm looking for would be something like

```
/Users/myUser/awesomeProject/some_module.js
```

The important part being the .js extension, since node would have had to fully resolve the path.

note: `require('path').resolve ...` does not solve this issue. What if some_module is actually a directory with a package.json inside of it, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out node has a way to do this! It's just not easy to find in their documentation. Calling

```
require.resolve('./some_module')
```

gives me exactly what I'm looking for

Here's the only reference I've found in the docs: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together